# Documentum connector in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

Today My manager was asked me for **Documentum connector** in SharePoint 2016, can anyone explain briefly or any understandable reference document on "Documentum connector".

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the business requirement? What do you want to achieve by integrating SharePoint and Documentum?

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for your reply, to be frankly I have no knowledge on Documentum.

Comment: it is better to understand if you can you explain what is your requirement here and you can check this tech net link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff721975.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint can basically integrate with external data in any connected system. But it requires advanced configuration and often custom development as well. Fortunately, there are many third-party vendors who can help you. I have not scanned the market thoroughly for Documentum connectors - but looks like EMC has their own [connector for SharePoint](https://www.emc.com/content-management/documentum-connector-ms.htm).

You might also take a look at the [Documentum connector](http://bainsight.com/documentum-connector-for-sharepoint) from [BA Insight](http://bainsight.com).

[Layer2](http://www.layer2solutions.com) can also help connect SharePoint to external systems.